# Cannot create new posts or upload images using media manager

Tags: posts, wp-admin, uploads, admin, media-library

My WordPress website was recently moved from one a shared hosting provider to a VPS setup at Digital Ocean. I provisioned the server myself and have WordPress running on a LAMP stack with Linux Ubuntu 20. The website itself is working when viewed from the front-end, but it is experiencing issues when trying to add new posts or uploading media.

When I try to add a new post, the following warning is displayed below the title field: *You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts*. The editor textarea and category blocks are missing, but ACF-related blocks and other plugin blocks like Yoast are still there. I have attached an image showing how it looks.

[image: WordPress add post issues]

I have checked the file permissions and ownership of the directories and files, and they are set correctly. All directories and files are owned by the www-data user and group. The only directory and files that are owned by my SFTP user is the custom theme.

I have run `sudo find /var/www/domain.ca/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and `sudo find /var/www/domain.ca/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`, but this has not resolved the issue.

I have added `define (‘WP_ALLOW_REPAIR’, true);` to the wp-config.php file and run the repair and optimize using http://domain.ca/wp-admin/maint/repair.php. All tables were listed as okay after completion.

I have tried enabling `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`, but only notices are displayed.

When I try to upload an image using the media manager, the following error is displayed in the Firefox dev console: *POST http://domain.ca/wp-admin/async-upload.php [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 399ms]* The server has its file size upload settings set to 8MB for `upload_max_filesize` and 10MB for `post_max_size`.

I can successfully edit existing posts and update media data like titles.

I can successfully execute a backup using the UpdraftPlus backup plugin.

The *Your homepage displays* setting under Settings > Reading displays *Your latest posts*.

When I save any setting, no success message is displayed by WordPress.

WordPress 5.8.2
PHP 7.4.26

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried switching to a default theme like Twenty Twenty-One? Did the same issue persist? How about deactivating all plugins and if the issue disappeared, then activate the plugins back one at a time until the issue reappears?

Comment: @SallyCJ I have tried switching to Twenty-Twenty One and individually deactivated/activated each plugin separately with no success. When I disabled the Classic Editor plugin, the post-new.php screen was blank. Also, when I deactivated the ACF Pro plugin, the plugin update system showed updates, but disappeared after re-activating it. Something strange is occurring on this setup.

Comment: @SallyCJ I have tried switching to Twenty-Twenty One and individually deactivated/activated each plugin separately with no success. When I disabled the Classic Editor plugin, the post-new.php screen was blank. Also, when I deactivated the ACF Pro plugin, the plugin update system showed updates, but disappeared after re-activating it. Something strange is occurring on this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to diagnose this issue as database-related. During the original importation of the data, it looks like something got corrupted in one or more of the tables. I emptied and dropped all of the tables and performed a clean import. Performing this action resolved the create new post and media upload errors.